# Locale not changing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, locale

I'm trying to make a Locale switcher in Laravel.

When User is logged, switcher works well, but when guest, nothing happens, I can't find the bug...

Here are my files:

In my Login view, I have my switcher:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="mexico" href="{{ URL::action('LanguageController@update', 'es') }}">
                        <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" alt="Español"> Español</a></li>
                <li><a class="english" href="{{ URL::action('LanguageController@update', 'en') }}">
                        <img src="/images/flags/GB.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is my LanguageController:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{

    public function update($locale){
        if(Auth::check()){
            Auth::user()->locale = $locale;
            Auth::user()->save();
        }
        Lang::setLocale($locale);
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

My routes.php

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'LanguageController@update'); // This is outside any middleware
```

I have a global middleware that handle Locale:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
        if (Auth::check()) {
            app()->setLocale(Auth::user()->locale);
        }
        else {
            $locale = Lang::getLocale();

            app()->setLocale($locale);
        }
    return $next($request);
}
```

If user is logged, locale is stored in db, otherwise, app locale is set up ...

By default Locale is in Spanish.

When I try to select English, it does nothing.

```
 dd(Lang::getLocale());
```

give me "en" at the end of LanguageController so, it should work, but if I put this same line

```
dd(Lang::getLocale());
```

in the login view ( it will get back there after return redirect()->back();), it gives me "es"

I don't understand why!!!

Any idea???

EDIT:

When I replace:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

with

```
return view ('auth/login');
```

it works.

Extending that, it seems that when I use redirect(), it will fail... Still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved it :

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
    {

        public function update($locale)
        {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                Auth::user()->locale = $locale;
                Auth::user()->save();
            }
            Session::put('locale', $locale);
            return redirect()->back();


        }
    }
```

LocaleMiddleware:

```
class LocaleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    protected $languages = ['en', 'es'];


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale') && in_array(Session::get('locale'), $this->languages)) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Inspired on [this post](http://pezo.net/2015/03/29/language-switcher-middleware-in-laravel-5/)